# MLRun - Can't access html pages locally. Error: MLRunAccessDeniedError('Unauthorized path')

Tags: python, machine-learning, devops, mlrun

I followed tutorial to learn mlrun and ran mlrun containers locally by mlrun [compose.yaml](https://docs.mlrun.org/en/stable/_downloads/8640717f7a38650d355cacd1809a11f5/compose.yaml).

https://docs.mlrun.org/en/latest/tutorial/01-mlrun-basics.html

The only difference that I did from tutorial is that set environment at beginning.

```
import mlrun
mlrun.set_environment("http://localhost:8080", artifact_path="./")
```

But I got 403 error (message: MLRunAccessDeniedError('Unauthorized path')) when see confusion-matrix.html and other html pages, but it is okay to see parquet file.

[Parquet content is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGIhj.png)

[403 on html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mMft.png)

Tried to change the file permissions to 755 but still get 403.

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Comment: @JIST, I use vscode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue and I solved it, see these possibilities:

**1. In case of external IDE**

- I used config file `mlrun-nonprod.env` with setting `MLRUN_DBPATH` (it is reference to MLRun API, for local installation, it is typically `http://localhost:8080`).
- I used this code in python, see

> import mlrun
>
> mlrun.set_env_from_file("mlrun-nonprod.env")
> project = mlrun.get_or_create_project(project_name, context='./', user_project=False)

BTW: You can also manually test this MLRun API, try to call `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/projects` and you will get list of all projects in MLRun.

**2. In case of jupyter (part of MLRun compose)**

- I used `compose.with-jupyter.yaml` see [link](https://docs.mlrun.org/en/latest/install/local-docker.html#use-mlrun-with-mlrun-jupyter-image)
- This jupyter notebook is preconfigured, you can directly create/get project, see

> import mlrun
>
> project = mlrun.get_or_create_project(project_name, context='./',
> user_project=False)